# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Закрытое соединение: next

Tags: java, исключения, resultset, connection

В коде в отдельном классе произвожу выборки и возвращаю ResultSet

```
public static ResultSet exe()  throws Exception   {

        ResultSet rout;

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
...


        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); // 1
        rout = rs; // 2

        stmt.close();
        conn1.close();

        return rout;
}
```

А вызываю и обрабатываю так

```
public static void main(String args[])  throws Exception  {

        ResultSet r;
        r = exe();
        while (r.next()){
            out(r.getString(1)); // Класс для вывода, работает
        }

    }
```

Я переписываю в новый ResultSet (2) и возвращаю.
Но у меня выводится ошибка

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Закрытое
>   соединение: next

Почему закрытие соединения влияет на копию ResultSet и когда мне тогда закрывать соединение? Объясните, пожалуйста.

P.S.: Причем, если не закрывать соединение, все работает нормально. Но его же нужно закрывать обязательно?

Comment: Соединение и курсор закрывать надо после того, как все строки будут считаны с .next().

Comment: А как же быть тогда? Построчно переписать в новый ResultSet и уже потом передать? Как-то так? То есть если я просто присваиваю, копия не создается?

Comment: Сразу переписывайте туда, куда вам нужно, только не в ResultSet.

Comment: А какую коллекцию для строк обычно используют, не подскажете? ))) Object()?

Comment: Хмм, смотря что вы с ней дальше собираетесь делатъ -  ArrayList,  HashMap или ваша самописная.